# Can aroma compounds travel through metal boards and glass?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, smell

A friend from customs said "if drugs have been in a glass jar for more than a day, the aroma compounds travel through the lid and the dog can detect it, especially after 2-3 days. They can travel through almost any material given enough time"

If you decanted freezing perfume into a very cold jam-jar and washed it it with water and set it to react for a few days at 25C', would the lid permeate enough aroma compounds to be detected, i.e. by a police dog or a bloodhound?

Comment: I doubt your friend knows what he's talking about. Most likely either outside of the container has been contaminated or the seal between the jar and lid is not tight enough. It's not like he would know

Comment: The part about the dog is possibly true. As for the rest... wait, how did the compounds get into the jar in the first place? Did they have to travel through the glass to get _there_?

Comment: On another note, the word "aromatic" in chemistry came to be used in a different sense, quite totally unrelated to what you mean. For that reason, I took the liberty of editing your tags.

Answer (score 1):

While as stated in my comment I don't believe this is the reason dogs can detect those substances, every material has a certain permeability for different molecules.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permeation